# What is this flying boat being restored at the Udvar Hazy Center?

Tags: aircraft-identification, seaplane

I am fortunate to live ~20 minutes from the [Smithsonian Steven F. Udvar-Hazy Center](https://airandspace.si.edu/udvar-hazy-center).  At the back of the Museum is there restoration hangar, surrounded on two sides by a second level glass enclosed observation walk which allows guests to look in on what is being restored.  Because these aircraft aren't actually on display, I was not able to figure out what type of plane this is:

[image]

I was originally thrown off by the wings in the background, clearly embossed with the German Iron Cross, but I don't think the flying boat in the foreground is German.  *Can anyone identify the plane in the foreground?*

Here's a link to the [original photo](https://goo.gl/photos/FxNEahU7g22H7R4n7), in case you want to get a closer look.

Comment: MUCH more interesting than some old Sikorsky is the Horten IX in the background!!!

Comment: @PeterKämpf it was so stealthy I didn't even see it until you mentioned it!

Comment: I'm guessing the wing sections belong to the Horten IX? They look about the right size/shape. Really glad to see it being restored...

Comment: [This one](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/horten-ho-229-v3), I assume?

Comment: What reentry vehicle is poking its way into the right frame of the photo? I've gone to the Smithsonian site and searched for the obvious keywords. It looks like an Apollo CM to me.

Comment: @IconDaemon Not sure so I've posted [the question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22699/which-apollo-command-module-is-pictured-here) on space.SE

Comment: @IconDaemon It's Apollo 11.

Comment: Thanks, all. To see [this spacecraft](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/command-module-apollo-11), amidst a few of its precursors in flight, is truly awe inspiring.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is a [Sikorsky JRS-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_S-43) (Like terry I thought it was a PBY as well at first glance, that center wing joint is fairly unique)

From the smithsonian website [you can find all the info on it here](https://airandspace.si.edu/collection-objects/sikorsky-jrs-1)

> This amphibious seaplane is the only aircraft in the Museum that was
>   at Pearl Harbor, Hawaii, on December 7, 1941. Ten JRS-1s were at the
>   U.S. naval base when the Japanese attacked during World War II. The
>   Navy immediately sent these unarmed utility craft to search for the
>   enemy fleet. The JRS-1 (used 1937-1944) is the military version of the
>   Sikorsky S-43 "Baby Clipper." On the day of the attack, the plane wore
>   a very colorful paint job: silver overall, black on the bottom, green
>   tail surfaces, a red band around the rear of the fuselage, and the
>   diamond-shaped squadron insignia behind the cockpit on each side. A
>   few days after the attack, ground crew repainted the plane blue, but
>   it has weathered and the original paint is peeking through. The
>   JRS-1’s current condition is due to many years of storage outside. The
>   Museum intends to conserve and restore the plane. Transferred from the
>   U.S. Navy, Bureau of Weapons

[image]

Comment: Good catch! I'm removing my incorrect answer.

Comment: Excellent find.  Just curious Dave, do you remember what you clicked from the website to find this?

Comment: @bclarkreston I did a search [here](https://airandspace.si.edu/collections/collections-on-display#!searchTitle=&searchExhibition=Restoration+Hangar&searchLocation=&sort=name&sortOrder=asc&page=0) for everything in the "Restoration Hangar"

Comment: There is another Sikorsky flying boat at Windsor Locks, CT, museum...a VS-44A, once owned by Maureen O'Hara and her husband.